# Validating integer values; c program

Tags: c

I need to program a code that asks the user to input valid positive integer values and then display error messages when it is not an integer for ex. if it is either a 0 , -1, or character/string. I tried making a do while loop so that it continues to scan again if the input is wrong, but it keeps an infinite loop. And this after this I need to take this value and plug it into a conversion function that I already have. How do I do that? Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanf(const char *format, ...);
int user_interface();
double convert(double);
void print_table(int);

int user_interface()
{
int Kelvin;
char term;
int status;
int wrong = 0;

printf("\t\n");
printf("Hello, and welcome to homework1a program where\n");
printf("this program will request input from the user to\n");
printf("enter a value for Kelvin and then it will return\n");
printf("the acquired integer\n");
printf("\t\n");


do
{
    printf("Enter a maximum value to show: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    status = scanf("%d%c", &Kelvin, &term);

    if(status < 0)
    {
        printf("WRONG This is not correct %d\n", Kelvin);
        wrong = 1;
    }
else if((status) != 2 || term != '\n')
    {
        printf("Error: %d\n", Kelvin);
        wrong = 1;
    }
 } while (wrong);

return 0;
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

void print_table(int num);
double convert(double Kelvin);
user_interface();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` --> UB, Hint: use `fgets` in conjunction with `strtol`

Comment: `void print_table(int num);
double convert(double Kelvin);` are useless declarations inside `main`

Comment: @DavidRanieri I’m really new to C program so I don’t know how fgets work Or what strtol- does :( and I became so used to using scanf.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala those are my other functions that I have to implement I just didn’t include it in this code cause I don’t need help with those parts as of now.

Comment: @Tracy yes, but you had declared them *outside* main function already

Comment: @Tracy With `status = scanf("%d%c", &Kelvin, &term);` and input `"abc\n"`, what do you expect to happen to those 4 key-stokes?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what I’m expecting is for the code to explain its an error of using characters and to Try retype in an integer again.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala are all functions suppose to go inside the main function in c programs? I thought it would be okay for it to be outside and I could just function call it inside the main function. I’m only familiar for Java so and new to c program so I’m not sure how everything works...

Answer (score 0):

**1. Program getting stuck in a loop after wrong input.**

So pretty much right now in your do-while loop you are using the "wrong" variable to determine if it should loop over again.
You have only been setting it to **1** when it is incorrect. It is getting stuck in a loop as the "wrong" variable is never being set back to **0**.
In the do-while loop you need somewhere to include "wrong = 0;"
It is up to you where you choose to do this, you can either put it at the beginning of the do-while loop OR after the else if statement you can add an else statement.

```html
else 
{
  wrong = 0;
}
```

Up to you how you want to implement it :) but just make sure the "wrong" variable gets reset or else once the user puts in the incorrect input 1 time the program will keep looping since the variable has not reset.

**2. How to get the value into your conversion function.**

So right now your "conversion" function can take in a double and the "user_interface" function returns an int so you can probably have the return statement plug in the value into the "conversion" function, but in saying that if you were expecting to receive a double in the "conversion" function I would recommend re-evaluating if the "user_interface" should be returning an int or a double.

Hoped this helped...

Comment: Hey I tried this and I’m not sure why but it’s still infinitely looping, I put in inside the beginning of the do while loop at the top before to starts printing everything else D;

Comment: Also I’m not sure why this happens but it doesn’t reject 0 or negative values either when I put the status < 0 there ... it still accepts it as a valid value n processes it

Comment: Even after setting wrong = 0; your scanf statement is prone to getting stuck as you made the 2nd term a char that has to equal \n in the 2nd else if loop. Be careful with this consider just having 
do{ wrong = 0;
   
 printf("Enter a maximum value to show: ");
    
fflush(stdin);
    
status = scanf("%d", &Kelvin);